# Spring/Eureka/Feign - FeignClient setting Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, netflix-eureka

When I use a `FeignClient` it is setting the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

If I use a `RestTemplate` to send the same message the message header `Content-Type` is correctly set to `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

Both the `FeignClient` and `RestTemplate` are using `Eureka` for service discovery, and I discovered this problem by debugging the HTTP message received by the server.

The controller on the server side looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/site/alarm")
public class SiteAlarmController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<RaiseAlarmResponseDto> raiseAlarm(@RequestBody RaiseSiteAlarmRequestDto requestDto) {
        ...
    }
```

My `FeignClient` interface in the service that calls the alarm looks like this:

```
@FeignClient("alarm-service")
public interface AlarmFeignService {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/site/alarm")
    RaiseAlarmResponseDto raiseAlarm(@RequestBody RaiseSiteAlarmRequestDto requestDto);
}
```

The HTTP message headers from the `FeignClient` are:

```
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_60
Host: smit005s-MacBook-Pro.local:9120
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 323
```

The alarm service doesn't like the `Content-Type` and throws the following exception:

```
2015-04-22 12:12:28.580 thread="qtp1774842986-25" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler" level="WARN" 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException: status 415 reading AlarmFeignService#raiseAlarm(RaiseSiteAlarmRequestDto); content:
{"timestamp":1429701148576,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/site/alarm"}
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    ...
    ... /* commented rest of stack out */
    ...
```

If I change the client side code to use a `RestTemplate` as follows:

```
@Service
public class AlarmService {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
...
    public void send(RaiseSiteAlarmRequestDto alarm) {
        RaiseAlarmResponseDto result = restTemplate.postForObject("http://alarm-service/site/alarm", 
            raiseSiteAlarmRequestDto, RaiseAlarmResponseDto.class);
    }
}
```

It works with the `RestTemplate`, the `alarm-service` receives the message and processes it successfully. The message headers sent by the `RestTemplate` are:

```
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_60
Host: smit005s-MacBook-Pro.local:9120
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 323
```

Comment: Have you tried ditching the `ResponseEntity<T>` of your controller to test if this was interfering with the Feign Client? My other guess is that Feign is not able to deserialize your `RaiseAlarmResponseDto` object.

Comment: The `@RequestBody` on the `@FeignClient` doesn't do anything.  Can you make a successful call without feign, but with eureka?

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb that was a good suggestion. Changing it to a RestTemplate does work, and it is discovering the service through Eureka. When I put debugging on the receiver side I can see the the feign client is sending it with the `Content-Type` header set incorrectly to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. While the `RestTemplate` sets the `Content-Type` to `application/json;charset=UTF-8`. I will update the question with this.

Comment: Have you tried adding `consumes="application/json"` to the  `@RequestMapping` on the `@FeignClient`?

Comment: Yes that works. But from the examples I've seen that should be unnecessary.

Comment: Hi @spencergib with a simple change I can recreate this on a feign example project of yours on githib. So should I raise a bug against spring-cloud for this? In meantime we can progress by using the consumes and produces directives as you suggested.

Comment: @user1232555 yes, raise an issue, reference this stack overflow question and tell us how you can recreate this.

Comment: hi, i think this issue is still going on, is it planned to be fixed in the future?

Answer (score 21):

The answer was to do as @spencergibb suggests; use the `consumes` directive in the `@RequestMapping` annotation on the `FeignClient` interface. This [Spring/Netflix documentaition](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#spring-cloud-feign) also has an example.

So for example the `@FeignClient` interface declaration in the client is now:

```
@FeignClient("alarm-service")
public interface AlarmFeignService {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/site/alarm", consumes = "application/json"))
    RaiseAlarmResponseDto raiseAlarm(RaiseSiteAlarmRequestDto requestDto);
}
```

Note this is only necessary on the client side and the server side controller does not need to have this change.

Would be nice if this was done by default on the `@FeignClient` and then it would be the consistent with `RestTemplate` and the server side controller `@RequestMapping` annotation. Maybe that can be done in a future release of `spring-cloud`.

Comment: It does not work for application/x-www-form-urlencoded you will get : feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.*.pojos.OAuthLoginPojo] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]

Comment: [adding custom converter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/57) doesn't work for me too

Answer (score 0):

**This is applicable for spring boot version 3**:

The default Content-Type used by Feign is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is why you're seeing this behavior. To change the Content-Type to `application/json;charset=UTF-8`, you can configure Feign to use a different encoder.

Configure Feign to use the **JacksonEncoder** by creating a custom **FeignConfig** class and annotating it with **@Configuration**:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {
    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new JacksonEncoder();
    }
}
```